# How to add CheckBox to Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-checkbox

I've tried using the following code but no checkbox appear, only text :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuShowDue"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
    android:title="@string/string_due"
    android:checkable="true"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Is it not possible to add it via menu ?  Should I do something else ?

I'm using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` as Toolbar.

Comment: Try changing android:actionViewClass to app:actionViewClass.

Comment: @Sameer Nice, it shows the `CheckBox`, but no text .. :)

Comment: Why don't you use : app:showAsAction = "always" ; probably it's not enough space and the text goes away

Comment: @Lazai, tried it, didn't work

Answer (score 11):

Please make changes as shown below to `app:actionViewClass` and `app:showAsAction` and it should work for you.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuShowDue"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:title="@string/string_due"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

Also make the relevant changes to onCreateOptionsMenu(). Sample text pasted below;

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) menu.findItem(R.id.menuShowDue).getActionView();
    checkBox.setText("Sample Text");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I want it to be action, I don't want it in the menu itself but over the toolbar

Comment: Please check if it serves your purpose. I have verified it to show the text with checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the title at OnCreateOptionsMenu. Use MenuItem should be sufficient.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem checkBoxMenuItem =  menu.findItem(R.id.menuShowDue);
    checkBoxMenuItem.setTitle("Sample Text");
    return true;
}
```

In OptionsItemSelected, check if checkbox selected or not:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menuShowDue:
        if(item.isChecked())
        {
            item.setChecked(false);
        }else{
            item.setChecked(true);
        }
        break;
}
```